# RDP Ubuntu Not Working

Tags: rdp

I'm trying to RDP to a Ubuntu VM from a Windows PC. However I get the error:

[image: Error]

I've installed xrdp and made sure it was running as well as let port 3389 through the firewall. I've also tried disabling the firewall, but nothing has worked so far.

Update 1: So I've managed to connect to the VM, but when I attempt to access another machine running Ubuntu it won't work.
I'm using the same settings as I did on the VM and connecting through a VPN so it is on LAN.

I'm able to SSH into the other machine. Firewall is disabled. Running
netstat I get:
[image: netstat]

Update 2:
I can't telnet into port 3389 on the machine.
Running netstat -plnt |grep rdp returns the following:
[image: netstat grep rdp]

Comment: To give useful input, we'll need a lot more information about the network topology - for example, is the connection between VM and host bridged or NAT? Is the Windows PC also the VM host, or is a separate machine? Are you trying to connect within the same LAN, or from an external network?

Comment: I've updated the info, see above. It seems to work not with the VM but not when I connect to a separate machine.

Comment: If your original problem with the VM is solved, please consider **answering your own question** by clicking the button below. This will help others. Ask a new question about the RDP with VPN with details about your network and VPN setup. Try disabling the VPN and use port forwarding instead to see it it works.

Comment: Basic network debugging steps: try connecting to the port, e.g. `telnet <ip> 3389`. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not actually sure how I solved the problem on the VM. I just did a clean install of Ubuntu again and it worked.

Comment: I can't telnet to that port. It works on the SSH port though.

Comment: Running the command: sudo netstat -plnt | grep rdp, it shows that \xrdp is listening on port 3389 but \xrd-sesman is listening on 3350. Could this be the issue. I've added a screenshot of this in the original post. It also seems like xrdp-sesman is using tcp6 while xrdp is using tcp.